# Python VScode cannot import pyodbc library

Tags: python-import, pyodbc

I am using VScode to run my python code.
I can pip install all my libraries without problem and also use them.
With the "Pyodbc" library I have a problem.
I can install it normally but when I want to import it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marvin/Documents/Python Projects /VSCode/SQL_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-311-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file)
```

Does somebody know this problem and could possibly help me?

Best,
Marvin

Importing the pyodbc library to connect with an azure sql database.

Comment: Try running `brew install unixodbc` and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried but I get this message: marvin@MacBook-Air-von-Marvin VSCode % brew install unixodbc
Warning: No available formula with the name "unixodbc".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.